# Why is my Postgres DELETE deleting zero rows, when one exists?

Tags: postgresql, triggers, foreign-keys

I have a table `transaction_metadata` with a row with primary key: `ac98435e-3eb3-11e9-8a32-4713408df551`, which shows up in a SELECT statement.

In a transaction, deleting it (`DELETE FROM transaction_metadata WHERE id = 'ac98435e-3eb3-11e9-8a32-4713408df551'`)  says that it deletes 0 rows. Later in the transaction, deleting a row that the `transaction_metadata` row referenced fails due to breaking a foreign key constraint.

How could this be? Why would the `DELETE` say it deleted 0 rows when it exists in the `SELECT`, and foreign key constraints say it exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out the issue was we had a trigger, where every time an operation was performed on a `transaction_metadata` row, we inserted a row into a `transaction_metadata_history` table that recorded the change. This table had a foreign key constraint on `transaction_metadata`, which must have caused the DELETE to not work.

As a workaround, we turned off triggers for the console session (`SET session_replication_role = replica;`), ran the `DELETE`s, then turned them back on (`SET session_replication_role = DEFAULT;`).